# 2 приложения на разных версиях руби на одном сервере

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, redhat

На компьютере установлен *Red Hat Linux*, *Ruby 2.2* и *GitLab*.

Мне нужно на него же поставить *redmine 2.5.5*, но он работает с *Ruby 2.0*.

*RVM* не установлен.

Подскажите, можно ли установить вторые руби 2.0 и запустить на этих рубях *Redmine*? Если можно - то как? Желательно уже установленный *GitLab* и *Ruby* не сносить.

Comment: *RVM не установлен* — настало время установить *rvm*?

Comment: Настало время установить Docker. Какая разрядность у OS, 64 бит?

Comment: Да, RHEL 64 Bit.

Answer (score 2):

Я предложу вас ортогональное решение, которое родилось из-за таких проблем: Docker. Docker - это средство *контейнеризации*, которое позволяет упаковать в образ целую операционную систему со всеми внутренностями, в том числе конкретной версией руби, php, конкретного приложения или вообще чего захочется - это очень похоже на виртуальную машину, но ею не является. Образу (точнее, созданному из образа контейнеру) *наплевать*, что там творится снаружи, он не видит внешнюю систему, а внешняя система не видит его. При этом Docker обеспечивает практически нулевую потерю производительности - сама ихоляция контейнера осущевствляется не им, а ядром Linux. Единственное, о чем требуется позаботится - это чтобы ваш RHEL (а точнее его ядро) [поддерживал](https://docs.docker.com/installation/rhel/) требуемые для докера фичи.

Чтобы запустить redmine версии 2.5.3 или 2.6.0 (2.5.5 отсутствует в этом репозитории, однако, возможно, есть в [других](https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=redmine) - их миллиард), вам нужно

- Установить [сам Docker](https://docs.docker.com/installation/rhel/)
- Установить [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) (насколько понимаю, версия для Ubuntu подойдет для RHEL - он написан на python и там на самом деле всего две версии, для мака и для линукса)
- Выкачать репозиторий https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine
- Переключиться на нужный тег (`git checkout v2.6.0`)
- Выполнить команду `docker-compose up -d` в корне проекта и подождать, пока файлы скачаются и редмайн запустится.

После этого redmine сам поднимется на первом неиспользованном порте в диапазоне 32768+. В последний раз инструктируемый по скайпу человек поднял редмайн менее, чем за десять минут. Единственное, что может потребоваться - это указать конкретный порт, для этого надо будет отредактировать fig.yml и заменить порт 80 на такую конструкцию:

```
"127.0.0.1:10000:80"
```

Это забиндит редмайн на адрес 127.0.0.1:10000, указание айпи позволит запретить внешний доступ. Останется только настроить прокси-сервер для внутреннего доступа, которым может легко может быть nginx с конфигурацией из единственного `location` c директивой `proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 1):

Устанавливаете RVM, затем
`rvm install 2.0`
потом в папке с красным шахтером создаете файл с именем `.ruby-version`, и содержимым `ruby-2.0.0-p353`. При смене папки на папку с красным шахтером будет меняться версия Ruby на 2.0